# Sort posts by custom field number

Tags: wordpress

I'm using this query do get some posts.

```
            $args = array( 
                'post_type' => 'spaces',
                'post_per_page' => '500',
                'orderby'     => 'rand',
                'meta_key' => 'space-city',
                'meta_value' => $search,                    
              );

            $query = new WP_query($args);
```

Now I need to order the results by total of comments on each post. I've a custom field with this number called "space-comments", but I've no idea how to sort this posts with this second meta_key.

I made some tests, but I only was able to get post when "space-comments" has a value. When there is no value, the post don't show up.

Any ideia how can I start?

Answer (score 0):

The WP_Query can accept a meta_query argument that is populated as an array of sub-arguments. That array can have sub arrays that are each their own meta query, so you can create some nice compound searches across meta data.

See the example from https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters below.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'product',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'color',
            'value'   => 'blue',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'price',
            'value'   => array( 20, 100 ),
            'type'    => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```